# How to join ListQueryable table and return toList();

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

Here is my code, I try to join two `ListQueryable` tables and return in `List();` but I only can return to `FirstorDefault();`

```
public async Task<TestModel> Report(TestModel model)
{
    var linkType = await _LinkRepo.ListQueryable(log => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name) || log.Code.Contains(model.Name))).ToListAsync();
    var click = await _ClickRepo.ListQueryable(log => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Code) || log.Code.Contains(model.Code))).ToListAsync();

    return  (from t in linkType
             join d in click on t.Id equals d.linkRepoId into sr
             from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where t != null
             select new TestModel
             {
                 Code = x.Code,
                 Name = x.Name,
             }).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

The problem is the code cannot return `ToList()` as it will return the error

> 'Cannot implicitly convert type'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code to return a list instead, change the return type of your method to `Task<List<TestModel>>` and change `FirstOrDefault` to `ToList`, something like this:

```
public async Task<List<TestModel>> Report(TestModel model)
{
    var linkType = await _LinkRepo.ListQueryable(log => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name) || log.Code.Contains(model.Name))).ToListAsync();
    var click = await _ClickRepo.ListQueryable(log => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Code) || log.Code.Contains(model.Code))).ToListAsync();

    return  (from t in linkType
                  join d in click on t.Id equals d.linkRepoId into sr
                  from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where t != null
                  select new TestModel
                  {
                      Code = x.Code,
                      Name = x.Name,
                  }).ToList();

}
```

Comment: saw your answer just after I posted a answer I was writing my answer when you posted otherwise I wouldn't have written

Comment: @PashupatiKhanal No worries, this happens a lot here :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method return type is `TestModel` so it is not being able to accept `ToList()` change your method to `List<TestModel>`  as:

```
public async Task<List<TestModel>> Report(TestModel model)
{
   //code here
   return  (
             //code here
           ).ToList();
}
```